# Python WebDriver - ChromeDriver.exe not working asking me for some permissions(!?)

Tags: python, google-chrome, webdriver

i have this code, and it's ending up with this error...

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    blablabla  ....
    OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

i gave  full permission for this folder and used run as admin on pycharm, the  py file and chromedriver.exe and nothing worked...

- i do have windows and i didn't saw a lot of  people using 'webdriver' with windows. maybe because of exactly this? idk...
- this "TinderBot" thing is because i following this youtube tut...

my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

full error

```
  G:\school\Python\PJ\TinderBot\Scripts\python.exe G:/school/Python/PJ/gui/TinderBot/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/school/Python/PJ/gui/TinderBot/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  File "G:\school\Python\PJ\TinderBot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "G:\school\Python\PJ\TinderBot\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Azoul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Azoul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Process finished with exit code 1
```

much appreciated!

Comment: Don't run this code as Admin

Comment: what else can i do?

Comment: which chrome and chromedriver versions do u use? cause the latest stable ones aren't compatible now.

Answer (score 2):

Run the **Pycharm** as Administrator and then run. It worked for me.
Initially, it was working from my C Drive and not from the D Drive. After opening as Administrator, it worked.

Another thing you can try is PATH or you can place the driver inside the Python..\Scripts folder and then can trigger the chrome without mentioning any location like the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PX8m.png)